# Автозапуск собственных команд django-admin

Tags: django

Создал собственную django-команду. Команда работает, все хорошо. Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли сделать так, что бы она автоматически запускалась при деплое/старте сервера? Если да то как?

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать [fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) ([форк для третьего питона)](https://github.com/mathiasertl/fabric/) .
Создайте файл с именем `fabfile.py` в корне проекта.
Пример для локального запуска двух команд:
`fabfile.py`:

```
from fabric.api import *

def start():
    local('python manage.py mycommand')
    local('python manage.py runserver')
```

Далее в консоли запускаем `fab start`

Comment: А зачем? Чем плох init любого приложения?